# Webview on android 5.0 don't show combobox content

Tags: android, webview

I writen a application use webview. When i run on android 4.4 or less, my application run normal. But when run it on android 5.0, my webview don't show content of combobox as on screenshot. When i use webrowser default of android, it load my web normal.

When i run my application
[image]

When i use webrowser default of android 5.0.
[image]

My code:

```
private WebView webPos;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    webPos = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webPos);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    try {
        version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        CallUrl wst = new CallUrl(CallUrl.GET_TASK, this,version);
        String Server = "http://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=longvan.mobile.softflowspos";
        wst.execute(new String[] {
                Server
        });
        webPos.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Đang tải..." + newProgress + "%");
                //Log.i("Url hiện tại là: ", webPos.getUrl());
            }
        });

        webPos.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.i("Error Web View Client: ", description);
                Alert alert = new Alert(SoftflowsPos.this, "Server đang bảo trì. Ứng dụng sẽ tạm thời đóng ngay bây giờ.");
                alert.showAlert();
            }
        });
        webPos.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);
        webPos.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webPos.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webPos.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webPos.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webPos.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webPos.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webPos.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webPos.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webPos.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webPos.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        webPos.setFocusable(true);
        webPos.setInitialScale(100);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webPos.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webPos.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        TestConnect testConnect = new TestConnect();
        Boolean flag = testConnect.execute(urlTest).get();
        if (isNetwworkAvailable() == true) {
            if (flag == true) {
                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    webPos.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
                } else {

                    webPos.loadUrl(urlServer);
                }
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(this, "Server đang bảo trì. Ứng dụng sẽ đóng ngay bây giờ.");
                alert.showAlert();
            }
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(this, "Thiết bị của bạn chưa có kết nối mạng. Ứng dụng sẽ đóng ngay bây giờ.");
            alert.showAlert();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Thông tin version bị lỗi: ", e.toString());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Kiểm tra kết nối bị lỗi: ", e.toString());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a same issue. Do you have a solution for this?